# Why does my Oracle CREATE trigger not insert records as expected?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have view LIVE_MATCHES (home,away,comp_name) and table MATCHES (priority ,sport,sub_list)

i need to create trigger that insert in TABLE from VIEW after view is updated or inserted doesn't mater and to check that unique column (sub_list) in table Matches isn't already inserted. Only need to insert from view is comp_name, sport and priority are fixed variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LIVE_MATCHES_TO_MATCHES 
    instead of insert ON LIVE_MATCHES 
   for each row
          declare
   p_priority number:= 1;
   p_sport number:=0;
   begin
     insert into MATCHES (sub_list , priority , sport, created) 

     select :old.comp_name , p_priority, p_sport,sysdate
     from dual
      where not exists (      
     select 1 from MATCHES 
    where sub_list = :old.comp_name);

 end;
```

I compile this trigger without errors but it does not insert data into table MATCHES.

Thanks

Comment: You are both inserting and comparing with `:old.comp_name`. It is going to be `null` for insert trigger  isn't it? . you should use `:new.comp_name` ,no?

Comment: Yes, i insert comp_name from view into sub_list to table.
As I get it old is for table or in my case view FROM which I want to copy data ?

Comment: @civesuas_sine - no; `old` is the values from the affected row before the statement is run. For an insert there was no previous row state so all the fields are null. [See this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tdddg/using-triggers.html#GUID-406D2D9C-7905-434F-9729-F9E2D8FCFAF7) and follow the link from there for more details.

Comment: Aha i get it. I changed it now to :new but still no inserts are made into table. One more thing this is force view created by external table and that external table is : 
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY NAME_OF_DIRECTORY
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
                                                        )
     LOCATION (SERVER:'live_matches.txt')

Comment: @civesuas_sine - edit your question to show the table and view definitions, and sample data, and the statement you are running that you expect to cause a table insert. But a view over an external table doesn't do any inserts, so there is no trigger firing point there; are you doing a further explicit insert into the view?

Comment: That is right , i found that external table doesnt do insert into view, so that is why I dont get and inserts into my table from view.
No it does not do any explicit insert into the view.  Is there any workaround process, maybe a job that will fire every 5 minutes which will call procedure or function and then inserting data from view or external table to my table. ???? any ideas ?

Comment: How will I create function or procedure from this trigger ?

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SOFTDEV."LIVE_MATCHES_SOCCER_T" IS 

   p_priority number := 1;
   p_sport number:=0;   
begin
INSERT INTO MATCHES ("sub_list","priority","sport","created")
SELECT LIVE_MATCHES .COMP_NAME,p_priority,p_sport,sysdate
FROM  LIVE_MATCHES WHERE LIVE_MATCHES .COMP_NAME <> MATCHES .SUB_LIST ;
commit;
end;

When i run this there is error which says  mathes.sub_list invalid identifier